# what does python3 -tt myscript.py do?

Tags: python-3.8

I just want to know what to expect when I run python3 -tt. Where can I find the information on python3 switches such as this? I looked on-line and in my python docs.

Thank you, sherman

Comment: In the documentation at python.org.

Answer (score 1):

This was only an argument for python2:

From the [python2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-t):

> Issue a warning **when a source file mixes tabs and spaces** for indentation in a way that makes it depend on the worth of a tab expressed in spaces. **Issue an error when the option is given twice (-tt).**

Since python3 doesn't allow tabs and spaced mixed this argument does not do anything.